# Putting blog content in firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I am creating a blog with Vue and firebase. I am wondering if it is possible to put the content of a blog in firebase database without first "posting" to the firebase data base? For example in Django site admin you can write the content directly in the database via the graphical user interface and retrieve the content that way.

I've looked around in firebase but I can't seem to find a similar feature. Maybe I've overlooked it or maybe I simply can't do it.

Comment: Firebase offer a console where you can add, edit and remove content. However, when you make that change, any apps that are observing those nodes will be notified of that change. Is that what you're asking?